# Multiple ajax calls jquery mobile

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile and I am generating buttons for each order.

When the order button is clicked it makes an ajax call to post a variable to an external PHP script to write in a database.

This works, but I am putting another ajax post in the succes handler of the first one.

```
function clickedbutton(buttonid,orderid){
    buttonid = "button" + buttonid;

    $.ajax({
        data: 'orderid=' + orderid,
        url: 'statusupdate.php',
        method: 'POST', // or GET
        success: function(msg) {
            $.ajax({
                data: 'orderid=' + orderid,
                url: 'getproducts.php',
                method: 'POST', // or GET
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#contenttwo").load("getproducts.php");
                    $.mobile.changePage($("#two"), { transition: "slidedown"} );
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

With the one in the succeshandler I am posting the orderid variable to getproducts.php

```
    // SQL query
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE OrderID = '" .$_POST['orderid']. "'";

    // Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    // Loop the recordset $rs
    // Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysql_fetch_array

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

       // Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array $row
       echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>';
       echo $row['productname'];
       echo '</td>';
       echo '</tr>';
      }
```

Somehow with the query above I am still getting all productnames even the ones of other orderid's loaded in my div. It is a multiple page jquery mobiles, so the pages are divs.

Comment: Warning: SQL injection possible; please use [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html)

Comment: try `cache:false` in your ajax params first. then I think also you meant `$("#contenttwo").html(msg)` to write the query result no?

Comment: Thanks a lot TecHunter that worked!!